# How to specify fragmentRootElementNames in StaxEventItemReader for nested elements?

Tags: spring-batch, hibernate-mapping, stax

Working with Spring-batch 4.1.2 to consume a complex XML and write to database.
Using StaxEventItemReader for reading XML data.

I am facing an issue for **nested elements**, while specifying **fragmentRootElementNames**.

```
 <bean id="productFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" ref="inputResource" />
        <property name="fragmentRootElementNames" value="ProductFeatures,ProductFeaturesDetail,SomeOtherNon-NestedFragmentNames..." />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="productMarshaller" />
</bean>

    <bean id="productMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.xyz.jaxb.ProductFeaturesType</value>
                <value>com.xyz.jaxb.ProductFeaturesDetailType</value>
                ...Some more types
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="productFileItemProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor"
        scope="step">
        <property name="classifier" ref="prodItemProcessorclassifier" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="prodItemProcessorclassifier" class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
        <property name="routerDelegate">
            <bean class="com.xyz.batch.CustomProdTypeClassifier" />
        </property>
        <property name="matcherMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="ProductFeatures" value-ref="prodFeaturesProcessor" />
                <entry key="ProductFeaturesDetail" value-ref="prodFeaturesDetailProcessor" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="prodItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter"
        scope="step">
        <property name="classifier" ref="prodItemWriterclassifier" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="prodItemWriterclassifier" class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
        <property name="routerDelegate">
            <bean class="com.xyz.batch.CustomProdTypeClassifier" />
        </property>
        <property name="matcherMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="ProductFeaturesDetail" value-ref="prodHibernateItemWriter" />
                <entry key="ProductParameters" value-ref="myListItemWriter" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myListItemWriter" class="com.xyz.writer.ListDelegateItemWriter">
        <property name="delegate" ref="prodHibernateItemWriter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="prodHibernateItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Here is the signature of the ItemProcessors

```
public class ProductFeaturesProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ProductFeaturesType, List<ProductParamEntity>>{}
public class ProductFeaturesDetailProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ProductFeaturesDetailType, ProductFeaturesDetailEntity> {}
```

XML structure is as follows -

```
<ProductFeatures>
    <Version>12</Version>
    <MessageEN>Welcome</MessageEN>
    <MessageFR>Bienvenue</MessageFR>
    <ProductFeaturesDetail>
            <!-- Some elements here -->
    </ProductFeaturesDetail>
    <ProductFeaturesDetail>
            <!-- Some elements here -->
    </ProductFeaturesDetail>
    <ProductFeaturesDetail>
            <!-- Some elements here -->
    </ProductFeaturesDetail>
    <ProductFeaturesDetail>
            <!-- Some elements here -->
    </ProductFeaturesDetail>
</ProductFeatures>
```

> Here, ProductFeatures has minOccurs=1, maxOccurs=1.
>   ProductFeaturesDetail is unbounded.

Each of Version, MessageEN, MessageFR need to be persisted as a record in Table-A which has 2 columns ParamName|ParamValue 
 Each ProductFeaturesDetail is a record to be persisted in Table-B.

> i.e. The 3 elements are each mapped to ProductParamEntity (i.e. with
>   ParamName=Version, ParamValue=12 ; ParamName=MessageEN,
>   ParamValue=Welcome etc.)
>
> Logically, ProductFeatures is NOT mapped to a table directly but data
>   is stored in 2 tables as List and
>   List into tables PRODUCT_PARAM and
>   PRODUCT_FEATURES_DETAIL respectively.

Here are the Objects - JAXB and Corresponding Entities

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ProductFeatures")
public class ProductFeaturesType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Version")
    protected String version;

    @XmlElement(name = "MessageEN")
    protected String messageEN;

    @XmlElement(name = "MessageFR")
    protected String messageFR;

    @XmlElement(name = "ProductFeaturesDetail")
    protected List<ProductFeaturesDetailType> prodFeaturesDetail;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_PARAM")
public class ProductParamsEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PARAM_NAME")
    private String              paramName;

    @Column(name="PARAM_VALUE")
    private String              paramValue;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_FEATURES_DETAIL")
public class ProductFeaturesDetailEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PROD_CATEGORY")
    private String              prodCategory;

    //---More attributes ---
}
```

Here is my Job Config :

```
<batch:job id="consumeProductFileJob" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="validateFile" parent="validateXMLSchema">
            <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="persistData" />
            <batch:next on="FAILED" to="notifyException" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="persistData">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="prodHibernateTransactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="productFileItemReader" processor="productFileItemProcessor" writer="prodItemWriter" commit-interval="500" >

                </batch:chunk>
                <batch:transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="notifyException">
            -- Do something---
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

> **Issue :** If I specify both as fragmentRootElementNames, only ProductFeatures elements Version, MessageEN, MessageFR are persisted
>   in Table-A. ProductFeaturesDetail is being ignored.
>
> If I specify just ProductFeaturesDetail, it works fine. But I dont get
>   the individual elements within ProductFeatures.

I want the data from both elements. What is the way to achieve this?

P.S. I am using HibernateItemWriter for persistence.

Comment: Is your `HibernateItemWriter` able to persist a `ProductFeatures` object with the list of its `ProductFeaturesDetail`s? If it is the case, then you don't need to specify multiple `fragmentRootElementNames`, you would only need to map a `ProductFeatures` element to a domain object persisted by hibernate.

Comment: @mahmoud : In my case, there is no entity mapped to ProductFeatures. Instead I have 2 entities ProductParam and ProductFeaturesDetail. 
The individual elements within ProductFeatures like Version, MessageEN etc. are mapped to a ProductParamEntity with ParamName=Version, ParamValue=12. So, it is like I have to persist ProductFeatures data in 2 different tables - one as a List<ProductParamEntity> for individual elements  and another as List<ProductFeaturesDetailEntity>.

Comment: Since you have two entites, how did you define the item reader which returns one type at at time? Do you have two different steps, one for each type? Please share the configuration of your step and the code of your entities to understand your use case.

Comment: @mahmoud : Updated config and entity structures. It is working as expected for all other fragments which are not nested. Only for these nested elements, I am facing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I added an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry my bad. The answer I gave initially won't work so I removed it. I forgot to mention that you need to use the super type (`BaseEntity`) for this to work. I have an example [here](https://gist.github.com/benas/b090647149b5148d7d58f195e300c09b) where each item is mapped to two items and each type is then written differently. It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but at least it illustrates what I meant. Using multiple `fragmentRootElementNames` is confusing to me because it means the reader can return multiple types, while its contract is to return a single type.

Comment: @DevikaBalasubramanian I have a similar problem while reading nested fragments xml structure, Did you find a way to solve, could you please help me with the solution ?  Thanks